# TextBox.Text Updated On DropDownList_TextChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DropDownList connected with an sqlDataSource and a TextBox .
I want every time the user selects a name from the column name listed on the DropDownList, 
the value of the column id of that item being displayed on the text of the TextBox

I made this code but doesnt seems to work:
(the code contains no errors)

```
protected void DropDownListIliaka_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string conString = "Data Source=icsd-db.aegean.gr\\icsdmssqlsrv;Initial Catalog=icsd12015;Integrated Security=True;";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

        string cmdText = "SELECT iliako_sistima_ID FROM iliako_sistima WHERE name = '" + DropDownListIliaka.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    iliako_sistima_id.Text = (reader["Iliako_Sistima_ID"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

}

Comment: Are you expecting the page to automatically trigger a postback when the value changes (without hitting a button first)? By the way, your SQL query has the potential to compromise your DB using a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Here's a [simple example](http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/01/adonet-command-parameters.html) on using SQL parameters with ADO.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the property AutoPostBack of DropDownList to true, so it posts back to the server and sets the value of textbox

Answer (score 2):

this

```
 string cmdText = "SELECT iliako_sistima_ID FROM iliako_sistima WHERE name = '" + DropDownListIliaka.Text + "'";
```

should be

```
string cmdText = "SELECT iliako_sistima_ID FROM iliako_sistima WHERE name = '" + DropDownListIliaka.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Depending on whether the selected value is different from the display text, this one also is valid: `DropDownListIliaka.SelectedValue`.